# How do I create a database within a docker container using only the docker-compose file?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create a database and connect to it within my container network. I don't want to have to ssh into a box to create users/databases etc, as this is not a scalable or easily distributable process.

This is what I have so far:

```
# docker-compose.yml
db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb/10-init.sql
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/tmp
      - PGDATABASE=web
      - PGUSER=docker
      - PGPASSWORD=password
```

This is my `init.sql` file:

```
CREATE DATABASE web;
CREATE USER docker WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE web TO docker;
```

When I start up the container and try to connect to it, I get this error:

```
db_1   | FATAL:  role "docker" does not exist
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | FATAL:  database "web" does not exist
db_1   | psql: FATAL:  database "web" does not exist
```

The first time this happened, I tried to create a role like this:

```
CREATE ROLE docker with SUPERUSER PASSWORD password;
GRANT web TO docker;
```

But it did not have any effect. To make matters even more confusing, when I use `node-postgres` to connect to the db, I get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

But how can the connection be refused if the db service isnt even up??

In a nutshell, these are the questions I'm trying to solve:

1. How can I create a database using only the files in my project (i.e. no manual commands)?
2. How do I create a user/role using only the files in my project?
3. How do I connect to this database?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider to upvote, accept or comment the answer if this solved your problem. It's The best way to say thanks to other people here at SO after they invested some time in posting them. Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you go ahead and accept an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I create a database using only the files in my project (i.e.
>   no manual commands)?

The minimal `docker-compose.yml` config for you defined user and database is:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=web
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
```

> How do I create a user/role using only the files in my project?

To execute scripts on database initialization take a look at the [official docs for initdb](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).
To get you started with a quick and dirty solution create a new file e.g. `init_conf.sh` in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL

    CREATE ROLE docker with SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';

EOSQL
```

And add the `volumes` directive to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
volumes:
  - .:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Recreate your container because otherwise, you wouldn't trigger a new database initialization. That means, `docker stop` and `docker rm` the old one first before executing `docker-compose up` again. STDOUT gives you now some information about our newly introduced script.

> How do I connect to this database?

To connect to your database with `docker exec` via the terminal:

```
docker exec -ti folder_postgres_1 psql -U myuser -d web
```

---

A `docker-compose.yml` in one of my production environments looks like the following:

```
services:
  postgres:
    logging: &logging
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
    build: ./docker/postgres  # path to custom Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
    env_file: .env
    restart: always

  # ... other services like web, celery, redis, etc.
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres:latest

# ...
COPY *.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Is adding `POSTGRES_DB` to my compose file enough to _create_ a database from nothing?

Comment: Yes, in fact, you could also leave this out because it defaults to ``POSTGRES_USER`` which defaults to postgres.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable you are using are wrong. Try this

```
version: '3.3'

services:  

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    restart: always
    environment: 
        - POSTGRES_USER=docker
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        - POSTGRES_DB=web
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    # optional port
    ports: ["5555:5432"]

volumes:
  db_data:
```

then from any other docker-compose service you can access the DB at `db:5432` and from your host machine you can access postgres on `localhost:5555`  if you also add the ports